# Can I stream podcasts from my Apple TV rather than downloading them?

Tags: appletv, podcasts

Apple TV lets me stream Podcasts, other devices (iPad, Mac, etc.) download them. Streaming saves on storage space, and Podcasts are "throw away" videos,so why store them... So is there any way I can get my "favorites" Podcast list from he Apple TV 2 to stream on other devices?

Answer (score 1):

Not really. You can, however, use an app like [InstaCast](http://vemedio.com/products/instacast) or [DownCast](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/downcast/id393858566?mt=8) to subscribe, stream or download podcasts. I use InstaCast everyday without any complaints.